# algorithm for finding a node in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

what is the algorithm used to write `Snode* find` and `set& operator=( set &rhs)` I just can't understand these two. I can read the code but I can't figure out why are they there. I can't understand the steps of the used algorithm.
Things I already figured out:
1. Snode is a function that gets a value and returns the node with the same data.but what do `prev` and `previous` do and what is `**previous` and why ahould we create a pointer to a pointer?
2. `set& operator=` is for overriding the = operator. but I can't understand what does it do after overriding.and why should we swap the `head`s of `temp` and `rhs` sets.
here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Snode //Snode class defines a node in a list
{
    char data;//a node includes a character
    int count;//an integer to count the occurrence
    Snode *next = NULL;//and a pointer to the next node
    Snode(char data, Snode* next) : data(data), next(next) {}
};

class set
{
private:
    Snode *head;//first node in the list
    Snode *tail;//last node of the list

public:

    set() : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {
    }

    set( set &src) : head(NULL), tail(NULL)//copy constructor method
    {
        Snode *temp = src.head;//set head of the second list as temp to travers

        while (temp)//untill the end of the list
        {
            // insert(temp->data);

            Snode *newNode = new Snode(temp->data,NULL);//create a new node with the same data and count
            newNode->count = temp->count;

            //now puts it in the right place
            if (!head)//if head = NULL (if sset is empty)
                head = newNode;//set the new node as the first node

            if (tail)//if tail != NULL (if set isn't empty)
                tail->next = newNode;//set new node as the next node of current tail, so it'll be the tail
            tail = newNode;

            temp = temp->next;//does the same thing for all the nodes of the second list
        }
    }

    ~set()//destructor method
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)//traverse the list and delete each node
        {
            Snode *next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
    }

    set& operator=( set &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            set temp(rhs);
            Snode *ptr = head;
            head = temp.head;
            temp.head = ptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool isAvailable(char value)//checks if any node with the same data exists or not
    {
        return (find(value) != NULL);//if find function can't find any, there's no same node
    }

    Snode* find(char value, Snode **previous = NULL)
    {
        if (previous)
            *previous = NULL;

        Snode *temp = head;
        Snode *prev = NULL;

        while (temp)
        {
            if (temp->data == value)
            {
                if (previous)
                    *previous = prev;
                return temp;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return NULL;
    }
    bool isFirst(char value)
    {
        return ((head) && (head->data == value));//if head's data is equal to value returns true
    }

    bool isLast(char value)
    {
        return ((tail) && (tail->data == value));//if tail's data is equal to value returns true
    }

    void display()
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " " << temp->count+1 << "\n";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void insert(char value)//to insert a new value
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);//if a node with the same data alreay exists
        if (temp)
            temp->count += 1;//increase the count by one
        else
        {
            temp = new Snode(value,NULL);//if if a node with the same data doesn't exist

            if (!head)//if list is empty
                head = temp;

            if (tail)//if list is not empty
                tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    int count(char value)//count the nodes by the counter temp
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);//travers the set
        return (temp) ? temp->count : 0;//if the list is empty return 0, else return the counter
    }

    void deleteFirst()//deletes the first node
    {
        if (head)//if list isn't empty
        {
            Snode *temp = head;
            head = head->next;//move the head forward
            if (tail == temp)//if loop faced the tail
                tail = NULL;
            delete temp;//delete the data
        }
    }

    void deleteLast()//delete the last node
    {
        if (head)
        {
            Snode *last = head;
            Snode *previous = NULL;

            while (last->next)//move forward untill the node before the last one
            {
                previous = last;
                last = last->next;
            }

            if (previous)//at the end of the list
                previous->next = NULL;
            tail = previous;

            if (head == last)//if there's only one node
                head = NULL;

            delete last;
        }
    }

    void remove(char value)//remove the node with the same data as the entry
    {
        Snode *previous;
        Snode *temp = find(value, &previous);

        if (temp)
        {
            if (temp->count > 1)
                temp->count -= 1;
            else
            {
                if (previous)
                    previous->next = temp->next;

                if (head == temp)
                    head = temp->next;

                if (tail == temp)
                    tail = previous;

                delete temp;
            }
        }
    }   };
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think your question is clear enough to get an appropiate answer. Can you try to pint point your question a bit more?

Comment: What has merging two lists to do with the `find` and `operator=` functions? Please update your title to be a proper short summary of your problem. And please update your question to elaborate more on the problem you have, what you're wondering about, and *why* you're wondering. Also please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @stefan edited!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdudeit was a draft, forgot it. edited anyway

Comment: If you skip the `prev` and `previous`, the find function must be pretty clear to you. The previous suggests some sort of being part of a recursive call, but it isn't. Contact the author and ask what that's all about. As for now these 2 variables have no meaning, besides that the inputted previous pointer is set to NULL

Comment: `why ahould we create a pointer to a pointer?` you should duckduck-go this... Its a way to instantiate a variable withing a function without using it as return value.

Comment: that was good info on duckduckgo. and yea, I got the whole```find``` except the ```prev``` things, gonna try calling the author again asap

Comment: @Stefan what about the operator? what changes after the modifications?

Comment: Well, if you are going to contact the author, you might as well ask him why the `=` operator isn't documented, but it seems that a whole chain of nodes is inserted at the position of `this`. That can explain the swapping: heads and tails need to be corrected... although I didn't see a correct implementation of the tail, which can be my bad, since I didn't dive into it really ;-)

Comment: You could test it's behaviour with a debugger..

Comment: The `previous` parameter of `set::find()` returns the pointer to previous node of the found node (if a non-`nullptr` address of a pointer to `Snode` is passed). This is used in `set::remove()`. It's pointer to pointer to make its use optional. (as it is usually done in C. In C++, I would've solved this slightly different: providing two `find()` methods - one with the `Snode *&previous`, and the other as wrapper without, which calls the former.)

Comment: The `set::operator=()` uses the copy constructor which makes a deep copy of `rhs`. The swapping between `this` and `temp` is responsible to let `temp` delete the old contents of `this` when it goes out of scope. However, as already suspected by Stefan I believe as well it is broken. Neither `tail` of `temp` nor `tail` of `this` is considered.

Comment: The assignment operator has to perform two jobs which are already available: 1. get rid of old contents - already implemented in destructor, 2. make a deep copy of `rhs` - already implemented in copy constructor. Making a local `temp` instance by copy is the first part of 2. Then `this` and `temp` have to swap their contents. For this, it is sufficient that they just swap their `head` and `tail` pointers. Now, `this` "owns" the copied contents of `rhs`, and `temp` owns the old contents of `this`. When `temp` goes out of scope it is deleted automatically whereby performing 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have guessed, `find` tries to locate a `Snode` containing the required character. If only that is required, you can ignore the `previous` parameter (it will be NULL), and `previous`/`prev` processing will just be useless.

But `find` is used in `remove`... In order to remove a node in a singly linked list, you must have the previous one point to the next one. So you must browse the list *keeping a track of the previous node*. That is exactly the way it is used in `remove` with:

```
            if (previous)
                previous->next = temp->next;
```

The assignment operator uses a close variant of the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/3545273). But as the destructor only uses the `head` member, only that member is swapped: that will be enough to have the destructor of `temp` to destroy all nodes of the original list.

Simply `tail` should be set in `this` even if it is useless to set it in `tmp`. A correct implementation could be:

```
set& operator=( set &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        set temp(rhs);
        Snode *ptr = head;
        head = temp.head;
        temp.head = ptr;
        tail = temp.tail;   // no need for a full swap here
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @sergeballeeta that's it! They're used in remove. Thanks

Comment: _But as the destructor only uses the head member, only that member is swapped: that will be enough to have the destructor of temp to destroy all nodes of the original list._ For all that, it will leave the `tail` of `this` in wrong state after assignment (i.e. point to a node which is destroyed or leaving it `nullptr` when it shouldn't), won't it?

Comment: @Scheff: Of course you are right! I had not noticed that `tail` for completely off... Post edited